Access new window api response data from parent window. but I don't have access of the code of new window
Problem Statement:
You have two browser windows, Window 1 and Window 2. In Window 2, an API call is made, and when the API response is received, you need to access the response data from Window 1. However, you do not have access to the code of Window 2, meaning you cannot directly modify it to facilitate communication between the windows.
Constraints:

No access to the code of Window 2: You cannot modify or add code to Window 2 to directly communicate with Window 1.

Limited communication between windows: Standard browser security restrictions prevent direct communication between windows or frames loaded from different origins, making it challenging to access data across windows without explicit cooperation.


Find a solution that allows you to access the API response data from Window 2 in Window 1, despite not having access to the code of Window 2.

TBH, I hope there is no solution. That would be a security problem.
